# INSERT INTO table SELECT Redshift super slow

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

We have a large table, that we need to do a DEEP COPY on it.
Since we don't have enough empty disk space to make it in one statements I've tried to make it in batches.
But the batches seem to run very very slowly.

I'm running something like this:

```
   INSERT INTO new_table 
   SELECT * FROM old_table 
    WHERE creation_date between '2018-01-01' AND '2018-02-01'
```

Even though the query returns small amount of lines ~ 1K

```
SELECT * FROM old_table 
WHERE creation_date between '2018-01-01' AND '2018-02-01'
```

- The `INSERT` query take around 50 minutes to complete.
- The `old_table` has ~286M rows and ~400 columns
- `creation_date` is one of the `SORTKEY`s

Explain plan looks like:

```
XN Seq Scan on old_table  (cost=0.00..4543811.52 rows=178152 width=136883)
      Filter: ((creation_date <= '2018-02-01'::date) AND (creation_date >= '2018 01-01'::date))
```

My question is:

- What may be the reason for `INSERT` query to take this long?

Comment: Take a look at the **Performance tab** to get an idea of what might be happening, both in the cluster and for the specific query. It should show whether you are being impacted by memory, IO, etc. Also, how many rows are in the `old_table` and what is the `SORTKEY` for the table? What does the `EXPLAIN` plan look like? Feel free to edit your question to add more details.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein updated the question with more info

Comment: Great! Next, you can separate the time to `SELECT` the data vs `INSERT`. Try `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM old_table WHERE creation_date between '2018-01-01' AND '2018-02-01'` — this will give you the time to run the SELECT portion. (You might want to slightly change the dates to stop it from using the cached results of a previous run of the same query.) If that is fast, then it would appear to be the `INSERT` portion that is slow. Again, it is worth looking at the **Performance tab** to look for the constrained resource.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I've tried running the `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM old_table WHERE creation_date between '2018-01-01' AND '2018-02-01'` part and it's fast. I don't see anything interesting in the Performance tab in the console, the CPU getting high to ~75%

Comment: Well, if the `SELECT` part is quick, the next part is `INSERT`. If you can, first `TRUNCATE` the destination table (warning: It will delete all the data!) and then try your Deep Copy (`INSERT...SELECT AS`). That will avoid problems with `VACUUM`. Another thing to try is to increase the **slot count**, which gives more memory to your query. Before the query, run: `set wlm_query_slot_count to 2;` and see if it runs faster.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I think the problem is `SELECT * FROM`, I mean when we fetch all columns (it's a huge table with ~1000 columns). Is there anything I can to with that?

Comment: Oh, another option is to resize your cluster to temporarily make it bigger, do the Deep Copy, then resize the cluster down. While it takes some time to resize, it's probably easier than breaking the task into smaller chunks. Vacuum will also run faster with more nodes/memory.

Comment: I already broke the task to small chunks, but every chunk takes really long time to complete, even when it has small amount of rows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my opinion, following are two possibilities--- though if you could add more details to your question will be great.

1. As @John stated in comments, your SORTKEY matters a lot in RedShift, is `creation_date` sortkey?
2. Did you do lot of updates to your `old_table`, if so, you must to vacuum first do `VACUUM DELETE Only old_table` then, do select queries.

Other option, you might be doing S3 way, but not sure do you want to do it.